# How to change proxy information for New Docker for Mac?

Tags: docker, http-proxy

When I do '`docker info`', I see proxy urls.

I am trying to bypass proxy while I am doing docker pull from home (outside work network).
My `.bash_profile` do not have proxy information either so I am not sure where docker info is pulling proxy url from.

How can I unset those proxy urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your version of docker (using VirtualBox, or using the new docker for [Mac xhyve VM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/#/docker-for-mac))

In both cases, you have a boot2docker VM: check if you see (after a `docker-machine ssh <your_machine>`) a:

- `/var/lib/boot2docker/bootsync.sh` which could set variables (including `http_proxy` ones)
- `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` which could declare `DOCKER_OPTS` with proxy urls in it.

Comment: so when I do `docker-machine ls` should I see at least one of the machine running? Now without doing anything(machine reboot etc.) I am not seeing previous proxy information in `docker -info`. I had thought with this new Docker For Mac we do not need to have another vm on top of the native OS, but looks like that is not correct.

Comment: Without doing anything, only machine reboot etc I am now able to do `docker pull` and everything is working now. When I do `docker-machine ls` I do not see any machine running. Now in future if I need to set proxy I probably will not be able to do it again because I do not know which machine to ssh into.

Comment: @jarus I don't know what version of docker you are using. If you are not doing any machine, that means you are using the new docker for mac, which involves a VM created for you. There should not be any proxy attached to this one.

Comment: my question was for new docker for Mac. I installed new docker for Mac and trying to find where it is picking proxy information from.

Comment: @jarus OK. That is always helpful to add as many information as you can in your question ;)